# Want Create Url in JHipster

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url-routing, jhipster

I want to create a url like this abc.com/firstName.lastName.how i am implement this in our project can you help me please.

i have check you filter in WebConfigurer.java class

```
        staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/");
        staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/index.html");
        staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/images/*");
        staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/fonts/*");
        staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/scripts/*");
        staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/styles/*");
        staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/views/*");
        staticResourcesProductionFilter.setAsyncSupported(true);
```

if i am change our url to abc.com/profile/firstName.lastName then it will work fine for me because i have write own filter like that

```
staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/profile/*");
```

but if i want to url like that abc.com/firstName.lastName for this url i have to change

```
staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/");
```

to

```
staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/*");
```

then it given a exception please provide me any way like regression.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this to be a UI url or an api call to get the user object?

If you want it to be an api call then you would need to add something like `com.ubnt.japi.web.rest.UserResource.getUser(String)`.

If you want it to be a UI path then you need to alter the AngularJS router provider in `/src/main/webapp/scripts/app/app.js`. I have not played with the generated angular files but you would probably be best served familiarizing yourself with routing in Angular before diving in. There are plenty of tutorials that can help.